# Border color on default input style

Tags: css, input, border

here's a tricky question...

I have default styled input fields (no css added, just width/height/padding), but now I want to give it a red border (error style). How can I do this? Just setting border will delete the default style of the input, setting only border-color will look weird, setting an outline will work in some cases (and doesn't look so good in Firefox).

Any tips?

**EDIT:** Come on guys read the question before answering. **I want the browser default look of the input**, I just want to give it a red border.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I would have thought this would have been answered already - but surely what you want is this: 
box-shadow: 0 0 3px #CC0000;

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/vmzLW/

Comment: You would probably want to use the `:invalid` pseudo selector as well.

Answer (score 19):

You can use jquery for this by utilizing addClass() method

CSS

```
 .defaultInput
    {
     width: 100px;
     height:25px;
     padding: 5px;
    }

.error
{
 border:1px solid red;
}

<input type="text" class="defaultInput"/>
```

Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready({
  $('.defaultInput').focus(function(){
       $(this).addClass('error');
  });
});
```

**Update:**
 You can remove that error class using

```
$('.defaultInput').removeClass('error');
```

It won't remove that default style. It will remove .error class only

Comment: As said to Ian Wood: That will override the default style for a input field, for example chrome has a inner shadow etc..

Answer (score 8):

whats actually wrong with:

```
input { border: 1px solid #f00; }
```

do you only want it on inputs with errors? in that case give the input a class of error...

```
input.error { border: 1px solid #f00; }
```

Comment: That will override the default style for a input field, for example chrome has a inner shadow etc..

Comment: you should use a reset css file - style the inputs how you want them and add the border when needed. different browsers do different things so don't worry so much about an inset shadow - some browsers won't even have that!

Comment: I want the browser default input, the input should look the way the browser wants, I just want to add a border.

Comment: Sorry for being short but if you apply some css properties that remove default styles implemented by the browser then you must find and implement those properties to re-instate them.

Comment: `you should use a reset css file` I strongly disagree with blindly using a CSS reset.

Answer (score 5):

If it is an **Angular application** you can simply do this

```
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched
{
    border: 1px solid red !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly this should solve it:

http://jsfiddle.net/wvk2mnsf/

HTML - create a simple input field.

```
<input type="text" id="giraffe" />
```

CSS - clear out the native outline so you can set your own and it doesn't look weird with a bluey red outline.

```
input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.error-input-border {
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}
```

JS - on typing in the field set red border class declared in the CSS

```
document.getElementById('giraffe').oninput = function() { this.classList.add('error-input-border'); }
```

This has a lot of information on the latest standards too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation

Answer (score 1):

border-color: transparent;
border: 1px solid red;

Answer (score 0):

```
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
```

Fix this setting in a class and apply it to your imput.